How to calculate the theoretical optimal Strike and Expiration for Covered Calls?
Given the following parameters:

Hold the call to expiration.
Estimate of probability of expiring ITM. (I know it is an estimate.)
Indifferent to being called away.
Only fixed number of shares available to be called away.
Fixed time to run system (say 3 years).
No early assignment.

What is the equation to find the optimal Strike and Expiration?
I can see that close strikes and ATM provide the most income. But far OTM strikes and distant expiration are best if the stock is called away.
I can also see that
expected profit = prob. ITM * (strike distance + premium) + (1 - prob. ITM) * premium

If the stock is called away the profit is the strike distance and the premium. If not, the profit is just the premium. But the stock is available to be used for another covered call.
It seems that this could be modeled with a Markov Chain or other probability math?
